# TCP Bandwidth throttling Slow VPN Speed

Tags: performance, tcp, vpn, throttling

My local ISP gives 2 MBPS speed for first 500 MB data.
After that speed becomes restricted to 64 KBPS.

I have a custom made Android TCP VPN ( TUN Based ) for Android ( Server Linux Centos)

After speed limit is reached My VPN becomes very slow I can not see youtube without Buffering. But I have tried few TCP VPNs for Android 
Out of those two VPNs considerably fast, even after speed limit reached. I can see youtube properly.

I have investigated. Out of two VPNs, one VPN use double TCP connections to server and split traffic  and send it via 2 different TCP connections which  may make it fast if ISP limiting speed per TCP connection basis.

But another VPN still using Single TCP connection like My VPN..But still it is fast.

**1.**   Please give me some idea about .how ISP limiting speed In this case and how to get maximum possible speed as other two VPNs doing. In MY VPN Encryption is implemented so ISP can not see data like other two VPNs.

My ISP limiting speed per IP basis?.or It is limiting speed per TCP connection .
Do I need to modify MTU size, TCP window scaling, send receive buffer size or anything in TCP settings both in Linux server kernel and Android client.
Because that VPN which using Single TCP connection also working properly with good speed.

I mean when Speed restricted to 64 KBPS...Those 2 VPNs can achieve 
40-50 KBPS  which is okay for Youtube non HD movie

Where as My VPN giving only 5- 10 KBPS. But at full speed My VPN is good like other VPNs. What I am missing in My VPN or server TCP settings.

**2.**  Also please tell me when I set TUN MTU value 1450 or 1500 both in server and client ...My TCP VPN working fine.
But if I reduce MTU to 1350 or 1370 ...It becomes very slow even at full internet speed. Browsing, youtube all are very slow.
As I thought decreasing MTU does not harm. What could be the reason? Surprisingly in few mobiles MTU 1450 ,1500 working fine but MTU 1350 1300 etc..gives very slow speed. For few other mobiles things completely different, there MTU 1350 working very good but MTU 1500 giving very slow speed. All testes are done in same mobile netwrok.  How to trouble shoot the issue

Can you please focus some light.

Thank you
pap

Comment: This is unrelated to programming and thus off-topic here.  Try superuser.com instead. Apart from that the bandwidth is limited in total by simply not forwarding any packets which would exceed bandwidth. It is thus independent from TCP connections, no need to look into VPN and no bypassing the limit with multiple TCP connections.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I  noted your advice on first question and from next time will post it in superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

For second question,
when you downgrade of MTU value, more ip packet is created. More IP packet means more headers and it will downgrade the server performance.
You should always use maximum MTU value and for etherenet it is 1500 byte.

Comment: I used android sample TOYVPN and modified it to use with TCP protocol.

Keeping TUN MTU 1500  ; I tried to  set TCP socket  property
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG =1350 
But no luck. Its behavior is unpredictable.

I have seen code of few open source VPNs , I see after reading TUN data , it is parsing IP packet and doing many jobs … But for me just  getting data from client TUN and writing to server TUN and vide versa. I  think  I am not doing wrong .( as in simpletun.c )

Any suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I minunderstood your problem. You are right you should always MTU of VPN interface lower 1400 bytes to prevent fragmentation  of encrypted packet. I checked you c file and it look like fine. I think the reason of problem is something else.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.